# Using exists in sql query

Tags: sql, firebird, exists

I only want to show orders which need to be invoiced. In the picture below, I showed two orders. I only want to show offerno 2200, because there is an amount (5000) that need to be invoiced. In both offerno's there is a row with termtype 6. This must be ignored.

I used the query:

```
Select
    salesorder.offerno,
    salesorderterm.termtype,
    Salesorderterm.invoiceamount,
    salesorderterm.salesinvoice
From 
    salesorder
Left Join 
    salesorderterm on (salesorder.objectid = salesorderterm.salesorder)
where 
    exists (select 1 from salesorderterm where salesinvoice = 0)
    and salesstatus = 1
```

However, the output shows both orders. This might be because of the row with termtype 6 and invoiceamount = 0.

How can I solve this?

[Attachment: Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C65b7.png)

Comment: You will need to add for which i think.  You are looking for where there is an order which needs invoicing, nothing related to returned invoceies as you have with the join, you have a join which you'll be able to us instead of exists `where salesinvoice = 0`  Exists is more for `select * from customers as c where exists (select 1 from orders as o where o.customerid=c.customerid)`

Comment: where salesinvoice = 0
and salesstatus = 1
and invoiceamount > 0

Comment: Where is the correlation in the sub query?

Comment: Your `exists` returns true for *all* rows as you are not correlating it.

Comment: please, put your sample data - BOTH TABLES not one - to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0

Comment: Why do you use LEFT join??? do you understand difference between INNER and OUTER join ? Read wikipedia and Gruber's "Essential SQL" classic book.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)  Using outer join might be your mistake here.

Answer (score 1):

The filter in the inner select is missing and it just checks if there are any salesorderterm with zero salesinvoice.
You need to add `salesorder.objectid = salesorderterm.salesorder` there too

```
Select
salesorder.offerno,
salesorderterm.termtype,
Salesorderterm.invoiceamount,
salesorderterm.salesinvoice
From salesorder
Left Join salesorderterm on (salesorder.objectid = salesorderterm.salesorder)
where exists (select 1 from salesorderterm where salesinvoice = 0 and salesorder.objectid = salesorderterm.salesorder)
and salesstatus = 1
```

But probably it is better if you just remove the exists and just add it as a filter.

```
Select
salesorder.offerno,
salesorderterm.termtype,
Salesorderterm.invoiceamount,
salesorderterm.salesinvoice
From salesorder
Left Join salesorderterm on (salesorder.objectid = salesorderterm.salesorder)
where salesinvoice = 0
and salesstatus = 1
```